# Sql Server Max function on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Below is my table data

```
 Mat   Phy Chem
 20 30  40
 25 35  35
 45 30  30
 45 40  35
```

I want to retrieve top 3 max rows of all the three columns in a single row.

O/P

```
 Mat  Phy Chem
 45   40   40
 25   35   35
 20   30   30
```

I have used below query but was unsuccessful, please help...

```
Select distinct top 3 max(mat) from studata group by mat order by max(mat) desc
Union all
Select distinct top 3 max(phy) from studata group by phy order by max(phy) desc
Union all
Select distinct top 3 max(chem) from studata group by chem order by max(chem) desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mat DESC) AS rn_mat,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY phy DESC) AS rn_phy,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY chem DESC) AS rn_chem
        FROM    mytable
        )
SELECT  q_mat.mat, q_phy.phy, q_chem.chem
FROM    q q_mat
JOIN    q q_phy
ON      q_phy.rn_phy = q_mat.rn_mat
JOIN    q q_chem
ON      q_chem.rn_chem = q_phy.rn_phy
WHERE   q_mat.rn_mat <= 3
```

Comment: I think that you should use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`, since the op can have the same value for each column and it wouldn't retrieve the top 3 distinct max.

Comment: I have done some little changes 
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY mat ) AS rn_mat,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY phy ) AS rn_phy,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY chem ) AS rn_chem
        FROM    studata
        )
SELECT   distinct q_mat.mat, q_phy.phy, q_chem.chem
FROM    q q_mat
JOIN    q q_phy
ON      q_phy.rn_phy = q_mat.rn_mat
JOIN    q q_chem
ON      q_chem.rn_chem = q_phy.rn_phy
WHERE   q_mat.rn_mat <= 3
order by q_mat.mat desc, q_phy.phy desc, q_chem.chem desc

Comment: @Quassnoi Can you explain how it works, this is the first time I have used this type of query.As im a beginner in SQL Server.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select distinct top 3 Mat
from studata
order by Mat desc

select distinct top 3 Phy
from studata
order by Phy desc

select distinct top 3 Chem
from studata
order by Chem desc
```

The reason you're probably getting a problem is because max is a function (it will only ever return 1 thing) so `Select distinct top 3 max(mat)` is nonsense.

Comment: thanks for the reply,It results only 1 row, i need to disply top 3 rows.

Comment: See my updated answer, because you want to separate the rows up you'll need three separate SELECTs.  If you really need it together, investigate temporary tables

Comment: you do need a `DISTINCT` somewhere, since this way you can have the same value on the top 3, and that's not what the op wants

Comment: @Lamak - You're correct I overlooked that, I've modified my answer